# Where can I find this proof of the Poincare-Hopf theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Last semesester, my professor told me about a very slick and intuitve proof of the Hairy-Ball theorem and where the euler characteristic comes itnto play. It goes a little something like this (for$2$-manifolds):

Assume you have a no-where vanishing vector field $X_p$ on your manifold $M$ and let $φ$ be its flow. Then you can find a triangulation such that the flow is transverse to the triangulation, which means that for every point at the 1 dimensional skeleton of the triangulation you have a direction where $φ$ pushes infinitesimaly the skeleton.

Now assume that you put an proton at every vertex, an electron at every edge and a neutron at every face. Then the total charge will be $χ(Μ)$.

But if you "let the wind blow" and let the flow move the triangulation, we get that now in every face we have a proton, an electron and a neutron, therefore the total charge is zero, which is absurd. Therefore, there exists a point where the field vanishes.

Now, he mentioned that Bill Thurston gave that argument. Unfortunately, our professor is a little hard to catch and ask him.  I would be very interested to know if this is written somewhere. A simillar argument has been given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52023/is-there-a-poincare-hopf-index-theorem-for-non-compact-manifolds) by Thurston himself.

Comment: This "argument" is not convincing: When you let the wind blow, I do not see that every face has total charge zero, because nothing stops multiple protons (or electrons) from entering the same face. [Also, to derive a contradiction we must assume $\chi(M)\ne0$.]

Comment: @ChrisGerig It took me sometime to be conviced too. But if you assume that the flow consistis of just "straight lines", which you can by the flowbox thoerem or whatever it's called, (theorem 9.22 at Lee's Smooth manifolds) then it is fairly easy to be conviced. I see it as an arguemenet mainly local (because of the infinitesimal moves) which uses the euler characteristic to transform it to a global one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Proposition 1.3.3 in Thurston's *[Three-dimensional Geometry and Topology](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/6086.html)*.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not on the free web draft, which is the only thing I have availabe since we don't have the book at the uni library. As soon as I check it I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you very much.